# Fatal error: Index out of range, Due to pressing like and heart button again and again

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

When ever I pressing like and heart button again and again, It crashes the App and says that "Fatal error: Index out of range".

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) - > Int {
    return activityArray.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) - > UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "activityCell") as!StreamActivityTableViewCell

    cell.likeButton.tag = indexPath.row
    print("....\(cell.likeButton.tag)")
    cell.heartButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.likeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(liked(sender: )),
        for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.heartButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loved(sender: )),
        for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell

}




@objc func liked(sender: UIButton) {
    let likebutton = sender.tag

    print("---- \(likebutton)  ... \(sender.tag)")
    let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "
        token ")!)"
    ]
    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "activity_id": activityArray[sender.tag].id!
    ]
    print(parameters)
    Alamofire.request(Constants.likedURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).validate().responseString {
        response in
            switch (response.result) {
                case.success(_):
                    if (response.result.isSuccess) {
                        self.activityArray.removeAll()
                        self.activityShown()
                    }
                    case.failure(_):
                        print("Error message:\(response.error!.localizedDescription)")
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry", message: "\(response.error!.localizedDescription)", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        break
            }
    }
}





 func activityShown(){

        SVProgressHUD.show()
                    let headers = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token")!)"]

                    Alamofire.request(Constants.activitiesURL,method: .get,   encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

                        if response.result.isSuccess {
                            let ActivityJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

                            let activityData = ActivityJSON["data"].arrayValue
                            let commentData = ActivityJSON["data"].arrayValue
                            for value in activityData {
                                let activity = Activity()
                                activity.name = value["name"].stringValue
                                activity.content = value["content"].stringValue
                                activity.published = value["published"].stringValue
                                activity.thumbnail = value["users"]["photo_thumb"].stringValue
                                activity.likesCount = value["likes_count"].intValue
                                activity.liked = value["liked"].intValue
                                activity.heartCount = value["heart_count"].intValue
                                activity.hearted = value["hearted"].intValue
                                activity.commentsCount = value["comments_count"].intValue
                                activity.commented = value["commented"].intValue
                                activity.id = value["id"].intValue
                                activity.currentID = value["users"]["user_id"].intValue
                                self.activityArray.append(activity)
                                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

                            }

                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                        }
                        else {
                            print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                        }
                    }
    }
```

Here, I‘m using Observer, Taking index.row from sender.tag, When I clicked on like or heart button, That API hits and give response. When I clicked more the one time than App crashes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why do you do this on succes?

> self.activityArray.removeAll()

The next time you call this function, you index into the array

> "activity_id": activityArray[sender.tag].id!

But it will be empty based on the code you have shown

If `activityArray` is changing and it appears that it is used for the table rows, you need to call `tableView.reloadData()` to empty the table

Edit -- after seeing updated code.

You have a few things wrong

1. You remove the data before you know if you have new data
2. You are reloading data in a background thread -- it always needs to be in the main thread

So,

1. Delete the line `self.activityArray.removeAll()` in `liked(sender:)`
2. Add that line here

```
if response.result.isSuccess {
   let ActivityJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)



   //// HERE is where we know we are replacing the data
   self.activityArray.removeAll()


   let activityData = ActivityJSON["data"].arrayValue
   let commentData = ActivityJSON["data"].arrayValue
```

And finally

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
```

This code needs to be like this

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.tableView.reloadData()
   self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Because the network calls are probably not completing on the main thread, but all UI code needs to be on the main thread.

EDIT: As Claus mentioned in their comment, a better approach might be to use deleteRows/insertRows and performBatchUpdates

I recommend that you 1st get everything working with reloadData() -- then go read the apple docs for https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614960-deleterows and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/2887515-performbatchupdates  and maybe watch this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MC4mDQ7UqEE

If you do it that way -- especially when you are not reloading the whole table -- iOS will do much less work and make a nicer default animation.

Comment: I‘m doing this, Bcz I want to reload data from API, If I didn't do that, It will duplicate that data.

Comment: Do you reload data when you change activityArray? It looks like you should

Comment: Also. You should tell us the exact line of code that has to error

Comment: When I click the like button, It sends data to the server, And I want to reload data from server using activityShow() before that I remove all data from the table,

because in activityShow() I use tableView.reloadData()

Comment: `"activity_id": activityArray[sender.tag].id!`this line of code

Comment: But you removed all rows. So that line is expected to fail

Comment: If I didn't do that, Data coming from server will be duplicated in tableView

Comment: Sir you are right. After Removing Both `self.activityArray.removeAll()`& `self.activityShown()`code is working good. But How can I update it in tableView

Comment: My guess is you need that code and that activityShown has a bug

Comment: `reloadData`, really? You know the correct solution is `deleteRows` (preferably in combination with `performBatchUpdates`...

Comment: how can I use that, and where ?

Comment: Ok, sure, delete and insert once you are more comfortable -- but first get this working.  In your case reloadData() is fine for now.

Comment: Ok Sir, I‘ll do that 1st

Comment: Claus is right that you usually want to tell the table exactly what you are doing to the data (deleting N rows, inserting M rows) -- because then the animation will look much better and iOS will do much less work in some cases.  Especially if it's not all of the rows (like if you deleted 1 row, reloadData would look very bad).  But since you are replacing all of the rows with completely new rows, you need to reload everything anyway.  You could always look up how to do that once you get it working

Comment: How we apply deleting N rows and inserting M rows ?

Comment: I recommend that you 1st get everything working with reloadData() -- then go read the apple docs for https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614960-deleterows and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/2887515-performbatchupdates  and maybe watch this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MC4mDQ7UqEE

Comment: Yes Sir, Fully working. thanks a lot Sir, Love U <3